# jQuery toggle next two elements

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a form select element that, when a certain value is selected, will toggle two other elements on the page (a dt / dd pair).

The event is triggered correctly, but I can't get the elements to toggle - note I am using class selectors because the number of these element "sets" on the page is variable. Here is my code:

```
$(".lender_id").change(function () {
if($(this).val()=='45')
   {
   $(this).next(".lender_other1").toggle();
   $(this).next(".lender_other2").toggle();
   }
});
```

lender_id is my select element class, html code as follows (as stated this element set can appear multiple times on the page):

```
<dt>Lender</dt>
<dd><select name="lender_id[1]" class="lender_id">
<option value="1">Value</option>
<option value="45">Special Value</option>
</select></dd>

<dt class="lender_other1" style="display:none;">Lender Name</dt>
<dd class="lender_other2" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="lender_other[1]" value="" /></dd>

<dt>Lender</dt>
<dd><select name="lender_id[2]" class="lender_id">
<option value="1">Value</option>
<option value="45">Special Value</option>
</select></dd>

<dt class="lender_other1" style="display:none;">Lender Name</dt>
<dd class="lender_other2" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="lender_other[2]" value="" /></dd>

etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you want:

```
$(".lender_id").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '45') {
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".lender_other1:first, .lender_other2:first").toggle();
    };
});
```

EDIT

I combined the class selectors together to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

[`next()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next) doesn't do what you think it does.  Try `$(this).parent('dl').find('.lender_other1')`.  Or, y'know, maybe just `$('.lender_other1')`.

Comment: I tried $(this).parent('dl').find('.lender_other1').toggle(); but it doesn't seem to work. Just $('.lender_other1') would toggle all elements of that class, when I need to only toggle the various next instance of that class. I've updated my question to provide better context.

Answer (score 1):

.next() only returns the next match, so I think you should be using .nextAll()

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/nextAll#expr

Comment: Would that be in the format $(this).nextAll(".lender_other1").toggle();? If so, that doesn't appear to work either. Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: Because the select isn't at the same hierarchical level as the elements you're trying to target.

Comment: good point - didn't see the <dd>. Don't see those tags very often. Anyway, you'll have to go up to the parent first, then use nextAll()

Comment: Just looking again, nextAll() won't work either as the other classes are at the same depth in the hierachy. I'll take a look at this again...

Answer (score 0):

use [slice(start, end)](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) method . this is the correct way according to a video of john resig.